# summing from two tables then preforming an operation with the 2 sums

Tags: sql-server, insert, sum, sql-update

I am using sql server and I have a table called accnt with the fields ven1 and amnt1 and a table called acc1167 with fields ven, job#, and amnt. for this example these tables look like this

```
   accnt                          acc1167
ven1     amnt1              ven     job#   amnt
1167     100                1167     1      200     
1152     50                 1167     2      300
1167     110                1167     3      100
1167     300                1167     4      200
1252     1050               1167     5      200
1167     210                1167     6      150
1167     1150 
1167     130 
2113     800 
1167     550
1167     1200
```

I need to sum amnt1 for all the records in accnt with the ven1 of 1167, we will call this sumA. Then sum amnt in acc1167 for all records, we will call this sumB. next I need to divide sumB by sumA to get a ratio. finally I need to multiply each amnt value from acc1167 by the ratio and get a number that will then replace the acc1167 amnt value.

for example, sumA = 3750, sumB = 1150. taking these values, sumB/sumA = 0.307. I then replace every value in acc1167 amnt with 0.307*itself, so the final table should look like this:

```
      acc1167
ven   job#    amnt
1167   1      61.4
1167   2      92.1
1167   3      30.7
1167   4      61.4
1167   5      61.4
1167   6      46.05
```

i have tried to use the sum function and and some insert, but i am very new to SQL and have never used sum before and don't know how to call from multiple tables, or how to store a ratio. Ive tried this:

```
UPDATE     acc1167
sum1 = sum amnt1 where ven1 = '1167'
from accnt
sum2 = sum amnt
from accnt
SET        amnt = sum2/sum1*amnt
FROM       acc1167
```

Comment: Any efforts to achieve your goal by yourself? Any problems faced? Or is it "write me a code" request?

Comment: Well, why don't simply show your actual attempt code instead of describing it?

Comment: edited the post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do it pretty straightforward and absolutely according to your task description:

```
declare @sumA decimal(29, 10), @sumB decimal(29, 10), @ratio decimal(29, 10)

select @sumA = sum(amnt1) from accnt where ven1 = 1167
select @sumB = sum(amnt) from acc1167
select @ratio = @sumB / @sumA

update acc1167 set amnt = amnt * @ratio
```

Comment: that replaced all the amnt values with null

Comment: @samhatcher it should not, if you have shown actual data. The behaviour you're describing is possible when your `@ratio` is null - and this can be only when `@sumA` or `@sumB` is null. `@sumA` can be null if there is no records meeting `ven1 = 1167` criteria in `accnt ` table. Probably your `ven1` type is string, not integer? Then it should be `ven1 = '1167'` in `where` condition.

Comment: well considering the actual table im using has ~10000 values that would be a bitch of a task. there are no null or 0 values anywhere on the table. and there are about 1000 records with 1167 as the ven1. and yes, everything is a string except for amnt which is a number. and i did put 1167 in ' ' when i tried the code

Comment: @samhatcher well, can't suggest more since I'm unable to see your actual data. Code snippet I've suggested outputs result as expected in question when being run on data provided in question (you can test it using declared tables kindly provided by Giorgi Nakeuri in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @accnt TABLE ( ven1 INT, amnt1 MONEY )
DECLARE @acc1167 TABLE
    (
      ven INT ,
      job INT ,
      amnt MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @accnt
VALUES  ( 1167, 100 ),
        ( 1152, 50 ),
        ( 1167, 110 ),
        ( 1167, 300 ),
        ( 1252, 1050 ),
        ( 1167, 210 ),
        ( 1167, 1150 ),
        ( 1167, 130 ),
        ( 2113, 800 ),
        ( 1167, 550 ),
        ( 1167, 1200 )

INSERT  INTO @acc1167
VALUES  ( 1167, 1, 200 ),
        ( 1167, 2, 300 ),
        ( 1167, 3, 100 ),
        ( 1167, 4, 200 ),
        ( 1167, 5, 200 ),
        ( 1167, 6, 150 )

;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, amnt * SUM(amnt) OVER() / 
                       (SELECT SUM(amnt1) FROM @accnt WHERE ven1 = 1167 ) namnt 
             FROM @acc1167)
UPDATE cte SET amnt = namnt

SELECT * FROM @acc1167
```

Output:

```
ven     job amnt
1167    1   61.3333
1167    2   92.00
1167    3   30.6666
1167    4   61.3333
1167    5   61.3333
1167    6   46.00
```

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, who knows? The main thing that solution works :)

Comment: i just tried this with my tables, using just the last part, since my tables are already made, and got a divide by zero error even though none of the ~10000 amnt values im working with are zero. what does the cte do?

Comment: @samhatcher, run this and tell me what does it return:   `SELECT SUM(amnt1) FROM accnt WHERE ven1 = 1167`

Comment: ok i figured it out. there was a negative amnt value added to the end of the table to cancel out all the added numbers from an accounting standpoint. i got rid of it for the time bing and the code worked